# In Java, are static class members shared among programs?

Tags: java, jvm

**I imagine that no, they aren't, because every process has its own memory space, of course.**

But how does the whole JVM thing actually work? Is there a separate JVM in a separate process for every Java program that I launch? Do Java programs running in a system share anything at all? Are there differences between OSs and JVM implementations? Can I *make* programs share variables (i. e. directly through the JVM rather than the usual IPC mechanisms)? Are there more exotic one-process JVMs for special purposes?

Generally, what are recommendable reads about the guts of JVMs? The [spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html)? The source code of some implementation? Websites? Books?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> In Java, are static class members
>   shared among programs?

A class is defined by its full name and the class loader that loaded it. If the same class is within the same JVM process and the two programs loaded the class through the same class loader then the static members are shared. Classloading rules are of extreme importance.

> I imagine that no, they aren't,
>   because every process has its own
>   memory space, of course.

If you are using two separate JVMs to launch two apps, you are correct. But take the case of application/servlet containers such as tomcat: they load several apps through the same process (the tomcat host process).

> But how does the whole JVM thing
>   actually work? Is there a separate JVM
>   in a separate process for every Java
>   program that I launch? Do Java
>   programs running in a system share
>   anything at all?

Every time you type `>java -cp...` at the command line, you are creating a new process. Bear in mind that when you run eclipse or call an ant java task with `fork=true` you are also creating new processes.

> Are there differences between OSs and
>   JVM implementations? Can I make
>   programs share variables (i. e.
>   directly through the JVM rather than
>   the usual IPC mechanisms)? Are there
>   more exotic one-process JVMs for
>   special purposes?

Like a poster said, there are projects like Terracota that facilitate this for you. A general approach for this kind of sharing is a distributed cache.

Answer (score 8):

No, static variables aren't between JVMs. Yes, there's a separate JVM process for each Java app you run.

In some implementations I believe they may share *some* resources (e.g. memory for JITted code of JRE classes) but I'm not sure. I believe there's ongoing work to enable more sharing, but still in a robust way. (You don't really want one JVM crashing to affect others.)

No, you can't make programs share variables transparently.

I believe there are books about the JVM, but I can't recommend any. You'd probably be best off looking for HotSpot white papers for details of that. [This one](http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/whitepaper.html) is a pretty good starting point.

Answer (score 6):

you should probably search more in the area of class loading if your main interest is about how static class members are instantiated.

Different threads on the same VM may have their own static class nember instances if they used separate class loaders.

The classic example here would be [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) keeping different web applications separate, though lib jars might be common to all applications.

Comment: +1 for the classloaders, that is what determines the scope of a static variable.  Not specific to the thread though, as the classloader can change even on a single thread of execution.  Quite common in JEE and OSGi environments.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the implementation, but yes there are ways things are shared.  There is/was work underway to change that, and Sun (via Apple) has done a lot of work in sharing data between instances of the VM.  There is a link that discusses some of that [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t72620.html?start=30).

To do any sort of sharing requires the VM implementor to do it, you as a programmer cannot do anything to make it happen.

The VM spec is [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html), there are some (older) books about it as well.  You can also look at the source for [Kaffe](http://www.kaffe.org/) which is pretty small.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share variables across JVMs, you could look at clustering products like [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/What+Is+Terracotta). They refer to themselves as "network attached memory" and let you share object references across JVMs using replication technology.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption. Yes, each JVM is a separate process. You can confirm this by opening Task Manager when you're running two Java programs (sort processes by name and look for java.exe or javaw.exe).

It is possible to make JVMs connect to each other (with local sockets, for instance), but there's nothing built in.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow on to what Kevin mentioned, there are no JVM implementations that I am aware of that allow you to share static variables across JVM instances.  As previous answers have stated (correctly) - each JVM instance is it's own process.

Terracotta (which is a clustering technology, not a JVM) allows for arbitrary sharing of object instances across JVM process boundaries - including sharing static variables.  Thus the moniker "network attached memory".  For all intents and purposes, when using Terracotta technology in your JVM process, all of the threads in all of the VMs behave as if they were all looking at a single, large, shared heap.  (With caveats of course, since that's not physically possible, Terracotta manages it through sophisticated sharing and replication algorithms which involve network io to move data - so therefore there are times when latency and throughput will not compare to native memory access)

There are abundant examples in the Cookbook section of the Terracotta site - I recommend you start with the Hello [Clustered Instance Recipe](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/Recipe?recipe=helloclusteredinstance) to get a feel for how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **static** variables are shared among the applications only those which are running on **the same JVM and having Same class name, and also having the same**
package's structure.

Like if, I am having the two projects **'A'** and **'B'** and the project 'A' is having the packages under **src like (com.azoop.eagle)** and project 'B' also having the same project structure as above **(com.azoop.eagle)** and having the same class name 'Example.java' containing the same static variable as '**static String logFile="./resource/sms.log**' in both of the projects. Then if both the projects are running in the same JVM instance then only they will share the same value of static variables. As static variables are loaded only one time in whole life cycle of the project after that they will be shared with the same value if not modified. This can happen only when both the classes should to loaded by the same ***ClassLoader*** among both of the projects.

I have faced this issue when I were having two different web-projects but they are running under the same **'WebServer' (JBOSS 7.3)** and having the same cases as explained above.