# How are java static variables maintained in JVM

Tags: java, static, jboss

I have an application that can be used by multiple clients to Log in at the same time. I have a static variable which am using. I wanted to check if its safe to use a static variable. I am using it in a public class. I wanted it to behave in a way that all the clients should have their own copy of that variable. Additionally I am using JBOSS to host the application.

Thanks

Comment: You can find some information about how the JVM treats static variables in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686079/in-java-are-static-class-members-shared-among-programs) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are stored in a special area of the heap called the **"permanent generation"**. Refer this [link](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-jvm-memory-types/) for more details.

> I have a static variable which am using. I wanted to check if its safe
>   to use a static variable.

Static variables are **class variables and only single copy of the variable** is created irrespective of the number of objects(instances) you create of that class. All the instances share same static object. So keep this in mind while using static variables.

Comment: I think it is worth clarifying that while static variables are stored in the permgen, it is specifically the primitive or reference that is stored there. If the variable is an object reference, then the object itself is stored outside permgen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple copies of a variable, don't make it `static`.

Comment: Or use multiple JVMs. If each client has its own JVM running the code, static would be fine. If the server has this code and all the clients talk to the server, then the variable would need to NOT be static and each client would need an instance of the class.